# How to get date in proper format from Json object in Java using jettison

Tags: java, json, date, jettison

Currently I am getting for

Input: `Date applicationDate;`

Output: `1318636800000`

How do I format this date output properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: replace 'now' to your applicationDate when you use this code.